# I get [Ljava.lang.Object;@ instead of data on my JTable

Tags: java, swing, object, netbeans, jtable

am trying to fill a JTable form from an existing `Object[][][] Array` the problem that i all the data or containing the `[Ljava.lang.Object;@` instead of my (integer) data even though i mad a `System.out.println("")` to print the data before putting them into the JTable but i always get the same problem ; here is the code next with a small shot screen and thanx for the help.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class gass extends JFrame {
  String title[] ={"Box", "Weight", "Priority"}; 
    public gass() {
        int nb=interface1.BNumber;
        Object[][][] data = new Object[nb][nb][nb];
        int E1=0, E2=0;
 for (int i=0;i<nb;i++)
            {       data[i][0][0] = i+1;
                    E1 = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
                    data[0][i][0] = E1;
                    E2 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
                    data[0][0][i] = E2;                  
             }
  for (int j=0;j<nb;j++)
              {       
              System.out.println("*"+data[j][0][0]+"*"+data[0][j][0]+"*"+data[0][0][j]+"*");
              }       
       JTable table = new JTable(data, title);
       Component add = this.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
       this.setVisible(true);
       table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
       this.setSize(800,400);
}
}
```

Another problem that i get wrong data always in the first cases of the Object Array `***data[0][0][0] = wrong information !!***`
next, a Link for a description of the output of my small application and thanks a lot for the help

[Click in this link here to get Description Image](http://s22.postimg.org/natscdyv5/Capture.png)

Comment: You are using a 3-dim array `Object[][][]` in the constructor , whereas the `JTable()`[constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#JTable(java.lang.Object[][],java.lang.Object[])) can take `Object[][]` !

Comment: i think you want something like `Object[][] data = new Object[nb][3]; ... data[i][0] = i+1; data[i][1] = E1; data[i][2]=E2;`

Comment: So is there any way to use a 3D array `Object[][][]` in the `JTable()` Constructor ?? @TheNewIdiot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JTable constructor takes an `Object[][]` as argument.

This array is an array of rows. So `data[i]` is a row, which is an array of columns.

And each row in the array is itself an array of columns. Each column (`data[i][j]`) should contain some data displayed in one cell of the JTable.

In your case, this data is itself an array. Since there is no specific renderer associated to object arrays, the `toString()` method of your array is used to display the array in the cell. And an array's toString() method returns something like `[Ljava.lang.Object;@`.

You should tell us what you would like to display in each cell, to get a better answer, explaining what you should do.

EDIT:

given what you want to display, you just need a two-dimensional array:

```
Object[][] data = new Object[nb][3]; // nb rows, 3 columns
for (int row = 0; row < nb; row++) {
    data[row][0] = row + 1; // first column: row number
    data[row][1] = Math.random(100); // second column: weight
    data[row][2] = Math.random(10): // third column: priority
}
```

Comment: I want to print a table containing 3 column : BoxNumber - Weight - Priority
the first is the box number 
the second is the weight Random 0-100
the third Priority Random 0-10
i just want to print the array in here :
 `for (int i=0;i<nb;i++)
            {       data[i][0][0] = i+1;
                    E1 = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
                    data[0][i][0] = E1;
                    E2 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
                    data[0][0][i] = E2;                  
             }`
into a JTable @JB Nizet

Comment: It's Solved and You Are Really awesome MR @JB NIZET  am so grateful for you with the comments i've understood how the object array works thanx a lot !